# Create a simple program to access a router

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, scripting

Good day Masters! I was wondering if it's possible to create a simple program like automatically open a browser and go to default gateway address and also auto fill up the info to login in a router and once it is logged in, It will automatically execute the reboot button of a router to restart, Since i'm having problem sometimes in my connection i need to manually reset by going to my router's gateway and click restart (I guess the only problem is my router not the modem that's why i wanted to reboot it). What i'm going to create is a 1 click button android app to automatically restart my modem, I just wanted to make things easier, what a lazy guy would do :D. If it is possible may you please help me with the sources or what do you call this type of programming sequences. I'm newbie when it comes to this but i'm eager to learn. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you don't even have to use a browser or a WebView. What modem/router are you using? Maybe it has an interface which you could talk to, other than the html one.

Comment: I used the WR-NET-024-ZI CD-R King router like usual router does. I wanted to make for example like Oberlo in shopify on which it automatically filled out orders with 1 click.